# Maven inherit parent module resources

Tags: maven, module, resources, pom.xml, maven-module

In Maven, is it possible to load resources in a child module from the parent project?

```
parent project
   ---child module 1
   ---child module 2
```

I have resources in the parent project `src/main/resources` which I would like to be made available for the child projects.  Ideally the child projects could override any of the resources.

Comment: Unclear. The parent project must be of `pom` packaging so there is really no such thing as "project resources" for this type of packaging. Could you post your real use-case?

Comment: I think its quite clear.

A parent project where the developer puts his resources, and the child modules would inherits by default during the packaging phase.

I just made a test myself and the package doesnt put resources of the parent into the target classpath of the child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to leverage resources from a library and / or override resources that are in the library is to put those resources in the class path. For e.g. say all common configuration are stored in `common-config.properties` and placed in the `src/main/resources` of the parent project. If an inheriting project needs to override the configuration, inheriting project can simple place the overridden file under its `src/main/resources`. In runtime, code should look for this property in classpath and right file will get loaded.