# How to share a checkstyle XML configuration/configLocation file between a global maven parent project and its users?

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle

I'm developing a Maven parent project (not aggregator!) project which contains Maven plugins and other things which I repeat in almost every project and which I want to use in projects through the

```
<parent>
    <groupId>richtercloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <relativePath></relativePath>
</parent>
```

idiom. `relativePath` is empty because resolution ought to occur throught the Maven cache as you probably know if you feel ready to answer this question.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>check_style</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <configuration>
                <includeTestSourceDirectory>true</includeTestSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <configLocation>check_style.xml</configLocation>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and thus `maven-checkstyle-plugin` is used in all projects containing `parent` directive above.

The thing is that

- either the `plugin` section above is put into `reporting` in the parent (without the `executions` because that'd be invalid), then the `configuration` is ignored and consequently the default XML being used
- or the `plugin` section is put into `build` in the parent POM, then the parent project doesn't compile because it doesn't search the file specified in `configLocation` in classpath ([which it should](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/multi-module-config.html) afaik) and thus fails due to `Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check (check_style) on project maven-parent: Failed during checkstyle execution: Unable to find configuration file at location: check_style.xml: Could not find resource 'check_style.xml'. -> [Help 1]`. Prepending `src/main/resources` helps to compile the parent, but causes failure in all other project because they resolve `configLocation` to `src/main/resources/src/main/resources/check_style.xml` which is correct. A bug?

This is not answered by [Maven inherit parent module resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33748939/maven-inherit-parent-module-resources) because the question doesn't specify how it references the `parent` project, i.e. with which `relativePath`.

I'm using Maven 3.3.9.

Comment: It does look the `configLocation` in the classpath. It fails building the parent because, when the parent is build, it doesn't have it (since the parent is declaring the plugin with `<plugins><plugin>` not in `<pluginManagement>` there is no reason it should be exempt from the checktyle). A better solution (IMO) would be refactor your `check_style.xml` in the parent's classpath, or refactor it into a shared library that the plugin's declaration in the parent depends on.